# lambda merge two list based on key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I need to create one list (l_merged) from 2 lists (l1, l2) by merging the value of their properties (prop1, prop2).

```
var l1 = new List<string> { "key1", "key2", "prop1" };
var l2 = new List<string> { "key1", "key2", "prop2" };
var l_merged = new List<string> { "key1", "key2", "prop1", "prop2" };
```

Where l1.key1 == l2.key && l1.key == l2.key2

Any idea? 
thank you.

Comment: Please use C# for your example, then people might be able to understand exactly what you want

Comment: What did you try so far ? Where are you stuck exactly ?

Comment: i saw the question asked before, i would not make concat or addrange. union is not working for me as shown on error post below. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may simply union them:

```
var result = l1.Union(l2).ToList();
```

Comment: That would produce `{key1, key2, prop1, key1, key2, prop2}`, which isn't what his example shows

Comment: i tried this solution and i get the following error: CS1929 'IOrderedQueryable<<anonymous type. That saying my list does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.Union<<anonymous type